# Input validation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying create a validation using JavaScript wherein input should be letters and space only. Every time I input a number it still passes the number input. Kindly look at my code below and help me out what's wrong in my code.

```
function validateForm()
{
   var x=document.forms["form1"]["fname"].value;
   if (x==null || x=="") {
      alert("Enter Firstname");
      return false;
   }
   else {
       if (!x.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/) && x.value != "") {
           alert("You entered an invalid Firstname");
           return false;
       }
 }
```

Comment: You're missing a final `return` statement and also `x` is already a string value. Calling `x.value` won't work

Comment: `x.value.match(...)` should be `x.match(...)`. `x.value != ""` should be `x != ""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You regexp should represent something like that

```
 /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/
```

There is special character for space (" ") - \s
Besides, there is an error in !x.value.match. You already have value of x.

So, your full function should looks like:

```
function validateForm() {
    // get the edit and get its value
    var edit = document.forms["form1"]["fname"].value;

    // if there are no value in the edit, or
    // there is only spaces and the string then return false
    if (edit.trim() == "") {
        alert("Enter your first name");
        return;
    }

    // else if there is something, then let's check it
    // this pattern allows any letter characters (both BIG and small)
    // and spaces
    // pay attention that the block inside this "if" will execute
    // if no matches will found (e.x if there will digits in the input string)
    // so it will works as we excepted
    if (!edit.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/g)) {
        alert("Enter correct first name!");
        return false;
    }

    // everything seems to be ok, return true
    // alert('ok');
    return true;
}
```

Example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/lagfrayg

Comment: Hey @Mark Zucchini, I tried your suggested fix but still it doesn't filter the input.

Comment: Sorry @Gelly. I wasn't quite thorough in first time. Now I have fixed the code.